# Create a map that contains information on a collection of objects

Tags: java, lambda, collections, java-stream

I have a collection of "School"; the class provides the method "getDescription" (String).
I need to create a `Map <String, Long>` which contains for every description the number of schools that have that description, using streams.
I did the following:

```
Stream<School> school = getSchools().stream();  // getSchools returns the colletion

Map<String, Long> m = school.collect(toMap(School::getDescription, 
        groupingBy(School::getDescription, counting())));
```

But it doesn't work... any tips?

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track. Try this:

```
Map<String, Long> m = 
     school.collect(groupingBy(School::getDescription, counting()));
```

Your original code:

```
school.collect(toMap(School::getDescription,   //
    groupingBy(School::getDescription, counting())));
```

will cause compile error, because `toMap()` take 2nd parameter as value mapper function

Comment: Wonderful! Where can i find some tutorial that explains how to make these "queries"?

Comment: You may gg for `java 8 stream tutorial`. I learned by experimenting on my collection and reading the doc so it's so hard to tell you how. But as initial step, you have to learn the meaning of some stream keyword: `map`, `reduce`, `collect`, `groupBy`, `filter`. After understand those keywords, you'll see that every stream collection is that a declaration of your desired operations

Comment: Well, even if the terms and principles are similar to "group by" or, "count" of sql queries, I doubt if the usage of these functions in java Stream can be called as "query".

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn for the record, under java-8, `Collectors.summingInt(x ->1)` will be faster than `Collectors.counting()`

Comment: I read somewhere they're the same. Because internally java did that way

Comment: Starting with Java 9, they are basically the same (except that `counting()` uses `long`). But in Java 8, `counting()` has been implemented as `reducing(0L, e -> 1L, Long::sum)`, which incurs boxing overhead. Since the result gets boxed anyway, this performance difference only applies to significantly large groups. And since this has been solved in Java 9, I wouldn’t waste too much time thinking about it. I might be interesting if you ever encounter a performance issue with an application right at this point when migrating to Java 9 is not possible…